# Is there a way to see the size of the current selection in the status bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

UltraEdit (*which I used before switching to VSC*) had a nice feature to display the size of the current selection in the status bar. Example:
[image]

Is it possible to achieve the same with VSC - either through native functionality or an extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can enable this feature by right-clicking your status bar and select "Editor Selection":

[image: 1]

It will look like this, then:

[image: 2]